# Java/Android access created Object in Activity from other Class

Tags: java, android, class, object, static

I am creating a object in the Main Activity like this:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public A a;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    a = new A();
  }
}
```

How can I access this in the Main Activity created class from another class like that:

```
class Class2 {
  a = MainActivity.a;
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You would either have to give that other class a reference to the A object using a set method of Class2 and call it in your main activity or make A static.

Comment: in `Class2` do you have a reference to `MainActivity`?

Comment: So would I just write the following code into Class2: `MainActivity mainActivity;` and then call it like `mainActivity.method` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to do so would be to simply have a static version of that object created in your `MainActivity`, but this would be unwise.

```
public static A a;
```

It would be better if they shared some form of a factory that held on to a reference of A and managed anything about it.  This way there is not a direct relationship between `MainActivity` and it's ownership of the class.

Something along the lines of

```
A a = AclassFactory.getInstance();
```

where the AclassFactory acts as a singleton that you can use to manage it between your main activity class and others using it.

Comment: Why would that be unwise?

Comment: The tighter the scope that you have on a variable and its class, the easier it is to manage and test.  Static variables can be accessed from anywhere and can't be analyzed from one instance to another as easily.  They can get confusing and should be used sparingly, but there are descriptions online of best practices for it.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that for further programming :)